# Существует ли какой-нибудь Id элементов на flowPane на java?

Tags: java, javafx

Я создал flowPane. На нем поместил 1 кнопку, которая отвечает за добавление VBox, содержащий свою кнопку и label. Каждый раз при нажатии кнопку на flowPane создается новый VBox. Также добавляю VBox в arrayList чтобы знать его номер. Теперь хочу сделать так, чтобы, нажимая на кнопку конкретного VBox - он удалялся с flowPane (remove(index)). Но как понять, что, нажатая копка, должна удалить именно свой же Vbox? Как понять к какому VBox относится именно эта кнопка?

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnAction( ae -> {
    flowPane.getChildren().remove( button.getParent() );
} );
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!